# Indefinite integral $\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\text{csch}^2 x}}\,dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I would like to know how to solve the following indefinite integral:

$$I=\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\text{csch}^2(x)}}\,dx$$

where csch$(x)$ is the the hyperbolic cosecant function of $x$, i.e. csch$(x)=\frac{1}{\sinh(x)}$.

I tried the substitution $u=\sqrt{1-\text{csch}^2(x)}$, which lead to $I=\int \frac{\sinh^3(x)}{\cosh(x)}\,du$. From the substitution relation I got:

$$\sinh(x)=\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^2}},\hspace{50pt}\cosh(x)=\frac{\sqrt{2-u^2}}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}.$$

There's the problem with the sign of $\sinh(x)$.  Since in the specific problem where I found this integral, $x$ is a function of $t$, $x(t)$ and this function isn't determined. Also, the substitution didn't simplify enough the problem. I also tried the substitution $u=\text{csch}(x)$, but I got similar problems.

Comment: Please show what you have tried

Comment: @clathratus Ok!

Comment: Note that $$1-\frac1{\sinh(x)^2}=\frac{\sinh(x)^2-1}{\sinh(x)^2}$$ So $$\frac1{\sqrt{1-\text{csch}(x)^2}}=\frac{\sinh(x)}{\sqrt{\sinh(x)^2-1}}$$

Comment: Shouldn't it be $|\sinh(x)|$ in the numerator instead?

Comment: Thank you for editing your question! (+1)

Comment: yeah i think so

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With $t=\sinh x$, i.e. $x=\text{arsinh }t$,

$$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-\text{csch}^2x}}=\int\frac{dt}{\sqrt{t^2+1}\sqrt{1-\dfrac1{t^2}}}=\int\frac{t\,dt}{\sqrt{t^4-1}}=\frac12\int\frac{\,dt^2}{\sqrt{(t^2)^2-1}}=\frac12\text{arcosh }t^2.$$

Comment: No, that would be $\frac{dt}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}$. It doesn't work.

Comment: @jmerry: fixed since.

Comment: @jmerry Thank you for your help. I will now study the problem related to $x$ signal.

Comment: @Élio Pereira: Uh - not my answer. I spotted an error that was then quickly corrected, but that's all.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thank you for help. (@jmerry I made a mistake, my intention was to thank Yves :), but anyway you should also receive some credit.)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative method.

Since $\operatorname{csch} x = 1/\sinh x$ we can write
\begin{align}
\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1 - \operatorname{csch}^2 x}} &= \int \frac{\sinh x}{\sqrt{\sinh^2 x - 1}} \, dx, \qquad x > 0\\
&= \int \frac{\sinh x}{\sqrt{\cosh^2 - 2}} \, dx
\end{align}
where we have used $\cosh^2 x - \sinh^2 = 1$. Setting $t = \cosh x$, $dt = \sinh x, dx$ one has
\begin{align}
\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1 - \operatorname{csch}^2 x}} &= \int \frac{dt}{\sqrt{t^2 - 2}}\\
&= \cosh^{-1} \left (\frac{t}{\sqrt{2}} \right ) + C\\
&= \cosh^{-1} \left (\frac{\cosh x}{\sqrt{2}} \right ) + C, \qquad x > 0.
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

To avoid sign complications, substitute $t= \coth x$ instead

\begin{align}
&\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\text{csch}^2 x}}\,dx\\
=&\int\frac{dt}{(1-t^2)\sqrt{2-t^2}}
= \tanh^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{2-t^2}}{t}
= \tanh^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{1-\text{csch}^2x}}{\coth x}
\end{align}
which is valid for all domain of $x$.